# Devexpress button to add different colour row

Tags: vb.net, winforms, devexpress, gridcontrol

I'm wondering if there is a way of adding `new row` to `GridView` which is different colour to rest of the `rows` in `Grid` ? I would like to add it when button is clicked.

What it would be used for is list of the feedbacks, the last one (which should be added on button click) should be resolution to the feedback and I would like it to be different colour to other `rows` in `grid`.

Please take a look at attached image of what I'm looking for:
[image]

If you need any more information, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!
Patryk

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your task correctly you need after click on button created only just one row. So when creating new row, set into help column value 1.

In `gridView1_CustomDrawCell` read row

```
DataRow row = gridView1.GetDataRow (e.RowHandle);
```

and if the help column contains 1, you finded the newly added row, and you can set it a different color:

```
e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
```

If i missunderstand, please write some details.

Answer (score 0):

You just want the new row in a different color than the existing rows ?
Have you tried setting the GridViews Appearance.TopNewRow.BackColor property ?
You can set it in the designer.